# How to get Azure Sql server port number in ARM?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-resource-manager

I am using an ARM template to get an azure sql server name but I looking for a way to also get the port (1433) instead of providing a hardcoded value.

My ARM code:

`[concat(reference(resourceId('Microsoft.SQL/servers/', parameters('database_server_name'))).fullyQualifiedDomainName,':1433')]`

edit: The resource manager doesn't list the port in the details but this port is given in the connection settings. [image]

Answer (score 1):

There is **`NO port number`** property for the **Microsoft.Sql/servers** resource type in Azure Resource Manager. Hence there is no way to read this from the SQL Server property in the template.

Below is the Resource Explorer in the Azure portal which shows all properties for the **Microsoft.Sql/servers** resource type.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I am familiar with the resource explorer and this is what precisely triggered my question.

Comment: Summer 2018, I also believe this is the case.  (Not a settable property.)  It seems very hard coded to 1433.  Long live memories of Sql Server 6.5 and 7.0!

Answer (score 0):

Do it the same as your database_server_name parameter:

```
[concat(reference(resourceId('Microsoft.SQL/servers/', parameters('database_server_name'))).fullyQualifiedDomainName,':', parameters('port_number'))]
```

Comment: Sorry, I didnt say that I haven't specified any port in my SQL template. I do not have the 'port_number'.

Comment: You can add a variable or a parameter to the ARM Template to add the portnumber.

Answer (score 0):

As of right now, the only port number that would be returned (if such a parameter lookup existed) for Azure SQL DB is port 1433; this is not surfaced in the API, as juvchan noted.

You could add a parameter to your [ARM Template parameter file](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/resource-group-template-deploy/#parameter-file), as pascal suggested to avoid a magic number occurrence in your code, since that seems to be what you're trying to avoid.

The contents of this file would then include something like

```
{
"$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
"contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
"parameters": {
... 
    "sqlazure_port_number": {
        "value": "1433"
    }
...
 }
}
```